# "Minimal" AES in CryptoJS sample not working

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

I have the following "minimal" AES test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="core.js"></script>
<script src="cipher-core.js"></script>
<script src="enc-base64.js"></script>
<script src="enc-utf8.js"></script>
<script src="aes.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_aes ()
    {
        var ciphertext = "0f71bc632c6aa13da599f310a54f0d280bcea1cbd96bbd214c5c3f9be7694de96755779a957416e8d8b1ebb635ad5f40";
        var key = "0123456789abcdef";
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
            CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext,key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>AES Test</h1>

<p><strong>Decrypted:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output"></span></p>

<p><input type="submit" value=" Go! " onclick="test_aes();"/></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the CryptoJS 3.1.9-1 files downloaded from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js/3.1.9-1 (which in turn points to Cloudfare's downloads --- e.g., https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js, etc.)

All of the included files are present  (I do Right-Click → View Source, then individually click on each of the `.js` files, and I see them).

If I run it exactly as above, I get error:

```
TypeError: Base64 is undefined
```

at cipher-core.js, line 619.

In addition to why does it not work, I have a general question about AES in CryptoJS: where is the mode of operation (CBC, etc.), the block size (AES-128, 192, 256), and the initialization vector?  (I guess that CrytpoJS.AES invokes some default).  Please clarify, or point me to any documentation (which I can't seem to find).

Comment: i would suggest using native crypto instead of a lib, no depends to worry about and battle-tested low-level implementations. you shouldn't copy files from CDNs, they often times process the script contents to make them load over the wire. you should use GIT to clone cryptoJS to a local source to avoid linking issues.

Comment: Is `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` undefined?

Comment: @Amy -- I don't know; for this "minimal" program, I'm not using and don't want to use Base64 encoding; the reason why I included the `script src="enc-base64.js"` was because of the error. I'm not invoking either `CryptoJS.Base64` or `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` in my program, so I'm quite clueless.

Comment: Just open your devtools and type in that code and see if it tells you undefined.

Comment: Thanks @Amy -- Seems to be ok (i.e., not undefined). I get output `CryptoJS.enc.Base64
Object { stringify: stringify(), parse: parse(), _map: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=" }`. Notice that I was reverting to CryptoJS 3.1.2, following dandavis comment (I originally had 3.1.2, installed through apt-get on my Ubuntu 18; given the error (same one), I found out about the newer version, so I tried downloading the 3.1.9 files (the link to github in the 3.1.9-1 page points to a 3.1.2 github repository!!!).  What should I try next?

Comment: @dandavis --- when you say "native crypto", what are you referring to?  That sounds to me like being part of the Javascript language, but I can't find any references to such thing.  (e.g., in w3schools' Javascript page). Can you clarify?

Comment: it's called the [WebCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). It's very powerful and flexible, and [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API#Crypto). I have a small [AES-centric wrapper](https://github.com/rndme/aes4js) for it if all you need is simple encryption and decryption and don't want to mess anything up...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the decrypt function takes input as object not the only string.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="aes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_aes()
    {
  var plaintext = ("0f71bc632c6aa13da599f310a54f0d280bcea1cbd96bbd214c5c3f9be7694de96755779a957416e8d8b1ebb635ad5f40");
        var key = ("0123456789abcdef");
  var output = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext,key);
  var original = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(output,key);
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = plaintext;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = output.ciphertext;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = original.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>AES Test</h1>
<p><strong>Plaintext:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output1"></span></p>
<p><strong>Encrypted:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output2"></span></p>
<p><strong>Decrypted:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output3"></span></p>

<p><input type="submit" value=" Go! " onclick="test_aes();"/></p>

</body>
</html>
```

In above code, you can see output.ciphertext attribute is displayed only but object is passed.
Since I have used cryptoJS earlier for my college project, that AES.js file is used by me. that file is giving me correct output. Maybe there's problem in aes.js file.
Here aes.js file that I used.

```js
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(u,p){var d={},l=d.lib={},s=function(){},t=l.Base={extend:function(a){s.prototype=this;var c=new s;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty("init")||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty("toString")&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},
r=l.WordArray=t.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=p?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||v).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,e=a.words,j=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(j%4)for(var k=0;k<a;k++)c[j+k>>>2]|=(e[k>>>2]>>>24-8*(k%4)&255)<<24-8*((j+k)%4);else if(65535<e.length)for(k=0;k<a;k+=4)c[j+k>>>2]=e[k>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,e);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<<
32-8*(c%4);a.length=u.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=t.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],e=0;e<a;e+=4)c.push(4294967296*u.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),w=d.enc={},v=w.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var e=[],j=0;j<a;j++){var k=c[j>>>2]>>>24-8*(j%4)&255;e.push((k>>>4).toString(16));e.push((k&15).toString(16))}return e.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,e=[],j=0;j<c;j+=2)e[j>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(j,
2),16)<<24-4*(j%8);return new r.init(e,c/2)}},b=w.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var e=[],j=0;j<a;j++)e.push(String.fromCharCode(c[j>>>2]>>>24-8*(j%4)&255));return e.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,e=[],j=0;j<c;j++)e[j>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(j)&255)<<24-8*(j%4);return new r.init(e,c)}},x=w.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(b.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error("Malformed UTF-8 data");}},parse:function(a){return b.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}},
q=l.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=t.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){"string"==typeof a&&(a=x.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,e=c.words,j=c.sigBytes,k=this.blockSize,b=j/(4*k),b=a?u.ceil(b):u.max((b|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=b*k;j=u.min(4*a,j);if(a){for(var q=0;q<a;q+=k)this._doProcessBlock(e,q);q=e.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=j}return new r.init(q,j)},clone:function(){var a=t.clone.call(this);
a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});l.Hasher=q.extend({cfg:t.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){q.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(b,e){return(new a.init(e)).finalize(b)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(b,e){return(new n.HMAC.init(a,
e)).finalize(b)}}});var n=d.algo={};return d}(Math);
(function(){var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib.WordArray;u.enc.Base64={stringify:function(d){var l=d.words,p=d.sigBytes,t=this._map;d.clamp();d=[];for(var r=0;r<p;r+=3)for(var w=(l[r>>>2]>>>24-8*(r%4)&255)<<16|(l[r+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((r+1)%4)&255)<<8|l[r+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((r+2)%4)&255,v=0;4>v&&r+0.75*v<p;v++)d.push(t.charAt(w>>>6*(3-v)&63));if(l=t.charAt(64))for(;d.length%4;)d.push(l);return d.join("")},parse:function(d){var l=d.length,s=this._map,t=s.charAt(64);t&&(t=d.indexOf(t),-1!=t&&(l=t));for(var t=[],r=0,w=0;w<
l;w++)if(w%4){var v=s.indexOf(d.charAt(w-1))<<2*(w%4),b=s.indexOf(d.charAt(w))>>>6-2*(w%4);t[r>>>2]|=(v|b)<<24-8*(r%4);r++}return p.create(t,r)},_map:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="}})();
(function(u){function p(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n&a|~n&c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function d(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n&c|a&~c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function l(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n^a^c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function s(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(a^(n|~c))+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}for(var t=CryptoJS,r=t.lib,w=r.WordArray,v=r.Hasher,r=t.algo,b=[],x=0;64>x;x++)b[x]=4294967296*u.abs(u.sin(x+1))|0;r=r.MD5=v.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new w.init([1732584193,4023233417,2562383102,271733878])},
_doProcessBlock:function(q,n){for(var a=0;16>a;a++){var c=n+a,e=q[c];q[c]=(e<<8|e>>>24)&16711935|(e<<24|e>>>8)&4278255360}var a=this._hash.words,c=q[n+0],e=q[n+1],j=q[n+2],k=q[n+3],z=q[n+4],r=q[n+5],t=q[n+6],w=q[n+7],v=q[n+8],A=q[n+9],B=q[n+10],C=q[n+11],u=q[n+12],D=q[n+13],E=q[n+14],x=q[n+15],f=a[0],m=a[1],g=a[2],h=a[3],f=p(f,m,g,h,c,7,b[0]),h=p(h,f,m,g,e,12,b[1]),g=p(g,h,f,m,j,17,b[2]),m=p(m,g,h,f,k,22,b[3]),f=p(f,m,g,h,z,7,b[4]),h=p(h,f,m,g,r,12,b[5]),g=p(g,h,f,m,t,17,b[6]),m=p(m,g,h,f,w,22,b[7]),
f=p(f,m,g,h,v,7,b[8]),h=p(h,f,m,g,A,12,b[9]),g=p(g,h,f,m,B,17,b[10]),m=p(m,g,h,f,C,22,b[11]),f=p(f,m,g,h,u,7,b[12]),h=p(h,f,m,g,D,12,b[13]),g=p(g,h,f,m,E,17,b[14]),m=p(m,g,h,f,x,22,b[15]),f=d(f,m,g,h,e,5,b[16]),h=d(h,f,m,g,t,9,b[17]),g=d(g,h,f,m,C,14,b[18]),m=d(m,g,h,f,c,20,b[19]),f=d(f,m,g,h,r,5,b[20]),h=d(h,f,m,g,B,9,b[21]),g=d(g,h,f,m,x,14,b[22]),m=d(m,g,h,f,z,20,b[23]),f=d(f,m,g,h,A,5,b[24]),h=d(h,f,m,g,E,9,b[25]),g=d(g,h,f,m,k,14,b[26]),m=d(m,g,h,f,v,20,b[27]),f=d(f,m,g,h,D,5,b[28]),h=d(h,f,
m,g,j,9,b[29]),g=d(g,h,f,m,w,14,b[30]),m=d(m,g,h,f,u,20,b[31]),f=l(f,m,g,h,r,4,b[32]),h=l(h,f,m,g,v,11,b[33]),g=l(g,h,f,m,C,16,b[34]),m=l(m,g,h,f,E,23,b[35]),f=l(f,m,g,h,e,4,b[36]),h=l(h,f,m,g,z,11,b[37]),g=l(g,h,f,m,w,16,b[38]),m=l(m,g,h,f,B,23,b[39]),f=l(f,m,g,h,D,4,b[40]),h=l(h,f,m,g,c,11,b[41]),g=l(g,h,f,m,k,16,b[42]),m=l(m,g,h,f,t,23,b[43]),f=l(f,m,g,h,A,4,b[44]),h=l(h,f,m,g,u,11,b[45]),g=l(g,h,f,m,x,16,b[46]),m=l(m,g,h,f,j,23,b[47]),f=s(f,m,g,h,c,6,b[48]),h=s(h,f,m,g,w,10,b[49]),g=s(g,h,f,m,
E,15,b[50]),m=s(m,g,h,f,r,21,b[51]),f=s(f,m,g,h,u,6,b[52]),h=s(h,f,m,g,k,10,b[53]),g=s(g,h,f,m,B,15,b[54]),m=s(m,g,h,f,e,21,b[55]),f=s(f,m,g,h,v,6,b[56]),h=s(h,f,m,g,x,10,b[57]),g=s(g,h,f,m,t,15,b[58]),m=s(m,g,h,f,D,21,b[59]),f=s(f,m,g,h,z,6,b[60]),h=s(h,f,m,g,C,10,b[61]),g=s(g,h,f,m,j,15,b[62]),m=s(m,g,h,f,A,21,b[63]);a[0]=a[0]+f|0;a[1]=a[1]+m|0;a[2]=a[2]+g|0;a[3]=a[3]+h|0},_doFinalize:function(){var b=this._data,n=b.words,a=8*this._nDataBytes,c=8*b.sigBytes;n[c>>>5]|=128<<24-c%32;var e=u.floor(a/
4294967296);n[(c+64>>>9<<4)+15]=(e<<8|e>>>24)&16711935|(e<<24|e>>>8)&4278255360;n[(c+64>>>9<<4)+14]=(a<<8|a>>>24)&16711935|(a<<24|a>>>8)&4278255360;b.sigBytes=4*(n.length+1);this._process();b=this._hash;n=b.words;for(a=0;4>a;a++)c=n[a],n[a]=(c<<8|c>>>24)&16711935|(c<<24|c>>>8)&4278255360;return b},clone:function(){var b=v.clone.call(this);b._hash=this._hash.clone();return b}});t.MD5=v._createHelper(r);t.HmacMD5=v._createHmacHelper(r)})(Math);
(function(){var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib,d=p.Base,l=p.WordArray,p=u.algo,s=p.EvpKDF=d.extend({cfg:d.extend({keySize:4,hasher:p.MD5,iterations:1}),init:function(d){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(d)},compute:function(d,r){for(var p=this.cfg,s=p.hasher.create(),b=l.create(),u=b.words,q=p.keySize,p=p.iterations;u.length<q;){n&&s.update(n);var n=s.update(d).finalize(r);s.reset();for(var a=1;a<p;a++)n=s.finalize(n),s.reset();b.concat(n)}b.sigBytes=4*q;return b}});u.EvpKDF=function(d,l,p){return s.create(p).compute(d,
l)}})();
CryptoJS.lib.Cipher||function(u){var p=CryptoJS,d=p.lib,l=d.Base,s=d.WordArray,t=d.BufferedBlockAlgorithm,r=p.enc.Base64,w=p.algo.EvpKDF,v=d.Cipher=t.extend({cfg:l.extend(),createEncryptor:function(e,a){return this.create(this._ENC_XFORM_MODE,e,a)},createDecryptor:function(e,a){return this.create(this._DEC_XFORM_MODE,e,a)},init:function(e,a,b){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(b);this._xformMode=e;this._key=a;this.reset()},reset:function(){t.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},process:function(e){this._append(e);return this._process()},
finalize:function(e){e&&this._append(e);return this._doFinalize()},keySize:4,ivSize:4,_ENC_XFORM_MODE:1,_DEC_XFORM_MODE:2,_createHelper:function(e){return{encrypt:function(b,k,d){return("string"==typeof k?c:a).encrypt(e,b,k,d)},decrypt:function(b,k,d){return("string"==typeof k?c:a).decrypt(e,b,k,d)}}}});d.StreamCipher=v.extend({_doFinalize:function(){return this._process(!0)},blockSize:1});var b=p.mode={},x=function(e,a,b){var c=this._iv;c?this._iv=u:c=this._prevBlock;for(var d=0;d<b;d++)e[a+d]^=
c[d]},q=(d.BlockCipherMode=l.extend({createEncryptor:function(e,a){return this.Encryptor.create(e,a)},createDecryptor:function(e,a){return this.Decryptor.create(e,a)},init:function(e,a){this._cipher=e;this._iv=a}})).extend();q.Encryptor=q.extend({processBlock:function(e,a){var b=this._cipher,c=b.blockSize;x.call(this,e,a,c);b.encryptBlock(e,a);this._prevBlock=e.slice(a,a+c)}});q.Decryptor=q.extend({processBlock:function(e,a){var b=this._cipher,c=b.blockSize,d=e.slice(a,a+c);b.decryptBlock(e,a);x.call(this,
e,a,c);this._prevBlock=d}});b=b.CBC=q;q=(p.pad={}).Pkcs7={pad:function(a,b){for(var c=4*b,c=c-a.sigBytes%c,d=c<<24|c<<16|c<<8|c,l=[],n=0;n<c;n+=4)l.push(d);c=s.create(l,c);a.concat(c)},unpad:function(a){a.sigBytes-=a.words[a.sigBytes-1>>>2]&255}};d.BlockCipher=v.extend({cfg:v.cfg.extend({mode:b,padding:q}),reset:function(){v.reset.call(this);var a=this.cfg,b=a.iv,a=a.mode;if(this._xformMode==this._ENC_XFORM_MODE)var c=a.createEncryptor;else c=a.createDecryptor,this._minBufferSize=1;this._mode=c.call(a,
this,b&&b.words)},_doProcessBlock:function(a,b){this._mode.processBlock(a,b)},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this.cfg.padding;if(this._xformMode==this._ENC_XFORM_MODE){a.pad(this._data,this.blockSize);var b=this._process(!0)}else b=this._process(!0),a.unpad(b);return b},blockSize:4});var n=d.CipherParams=l.extend({init:function(a){this.mixIn(a)},toString:function(a){return(a||this.formatter).stringify(this)}}),b=(p.format={}).OpenSSL={stringify:function(a){var b=a.ciphertext;a=a.salt;return(a?s.create([1398893684,
1701076831]).concat(a).concat(b):b).toString(r)},parse:function(a){a=r.parse(a);var b=a.words;if(1398893684==b[0]&&1701076831==b[1]){var c=s.create(b.slice(2,4));b.splice(0,4);a.sigBytes-=16}return n.create({ciphertext:a,salt:c})}},a=d.SerializableCipher=l.extend({cfg:l.extend({format:b}),encrypt:function(a,b,c,d){d=this.cfg.extend(d);var l=a.createEncryptor(c,d);b=l.finalize(b);l=l.cfg;return n.create({ciphertext:b,key:c,iv:l.iv,algorithm:a,mode:l.mode,padding:l.padding,blockSize:a.blockSize,formatter:d.format})},
decrypt:function(a,b,c,d){d=this.cfg.extend(d);b=this._parse(b,d.format);return a.createDecryptor(c,d).finalize(b.ciphertext)},_parse:function(a,b){return"string"==typeof a?b.parse(a,this):a}}),p=(p.kdf={}).OpenSSL={execute:function(a,b,c,d){d||(d=s.random(8));a=w.create({keySize:b+c}).compute(a,d);c=s.create(a.words.slice(b),4*c);a.sigBytes=4*b;return n.create({key:a,iv:c,salt:d})}},c=d.PasswordBasedCipher=a.extend({cfg:a.cfg.extend({kdf:p}),encrypt:function(b,c,d,l){l=this.cfg.extend(l);d=l.kdf.execute(d,
b.keySize,b.ivSize);l.iv=d.iv;b=a.encrypt.call(this,b,c,d.key,l);b.mixIn(d);return b},decrypt:function(b,c,d,l){l=this.cfg.extend(l);c=this._parse(c,l.format);d=l.kdf.execute(d,b.keySize,b.ivSize,c.salt);l.iv=d.iv;return a.decrypt.call(this,b,c,d.key,l)}})}();
(function(){for(var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib.BlockCipher,d=u.algo,l=[],s=[],t=[],r=[],w=[],v=[],b=[],x=[],q=[],n=[],a=[],c=0;256>c;c++)a[c]=128>c?c<<1:c<<1^283;for(var e=0,j=0,c=0;256>c;c++){var k=j^j<<1^j<<2^j<<3^j<<4,k=k>>>8^k&255^99;l[e]=k;s[k]=e;var z=a[e],F=a[z],G=a[F],y=257*a[k]^16843008*k;t[e]=y<<24|y>>>8;r[e]=y<<16|y>>>16;w[e]=y<<8|y>>>24;v[e]=y;y=16843009*G^65537*F^257*z^16843008*e;b[k]=y<<24|y>>>8;x[k]=y<<16|y>>>16;q[k]=y<<8|y>>>24;n[k]=y;e?(e=z^a[a[a[G^z]]],j^=a[a[j]]):e=j=1}var H=[0,1,2,4,8,
16,32,64,128,27,54],d=d.AES=p.extend({_doReset:function(){for(var a=this._key,c=a.words,d=a.sigBytes/4,a=4*((this._nRounds=d+6)+1),e=this._keySchedule=[],j=0;j<a;j++)if(j<d)e[j]=c[j];else{var k=e[j-1];j%d?6<d&&4==j%d&&(k=l[k>>>24]<<24|l[k>>>16&255]<<16|l[k>>>8&255]<<8|l[k&255]):(k=k<<8|k>>>24,k=l[k>>>24]<<24|l[k>>>16&255]<<16|l[k>>>8&255]<<8|l[k&255],k^=H[j/d|0]<<24);e[j]=e[j-d]^k}c=this._invKeySchedule=[];for(d=0;d<a;d++)j=a-d,k=d%4?e[j]:e[j-4],c[d]=4>d||4>=j?k:b[l[k>>>24]]^x[l[k>>>16&255]]^q[l[k>>>
8&255]]^n[l[k&255]]},encryptBlock:function(a,b){this._doCryptBlock(a,b,this._keySchedule,t,r,w,v,l)},decryptBlock:function(a,c){var d=a[c+1];a[c+1]=a[c+3];a[c+3]=d;this._doCryptBlock(a,c,this._invKeySchedule,b,x,q,n,s);d=a[c+1];a[c+1]=a[c+3];a[c+3]=d},_doCryptBlock:function(a,b,c,d,e,j,l,f){for(var m=this._nRounds,g=a[b]^c[0],h=a[b+1]^c[1],k=a[b+2]^c[2],n=a[b+3]^c[3],p=4,r=1;r<m;r++)var q=d[g>>>24]^e[h>>>16&255]^j[k>>>8&255]^l[n&255]^c[p++],s=d[h>>>24]^e[k>>>16&255]^j[n>>>8&255]^l[g&255]^c[p++],t=
d[k>>>24]^e[n>>>16&255]^j[g>>>8&255]^l[h&255]^c[p++],n=d[n>>>24]^e[g>>>16&255]^j[h>>>8&255]^l[k&255]^c[p++],g=q,h=s,k=t;q=(f[g>>>24]<<24|f[h>>>16&255]<<16|f[k>>>8&255]<<8|f[n&255])^c[p++];s=(f[h>>>24]<<24|f[k>>>16&255]<<16|f[n>>>8&255]<<8|f[g&255])^c[p++];t=(f[k>>>24]<<24|f[n>>>16&255]<<16|f[g>>>8&255]<<8|f[h&255])^c[p++];n=(f[n>>>24]<<24|f[g>>>16&255]<<16|f[h>>>8&255]<<8|f[k&255])^c[p++];a[b]=q;a[b+1]=s;a[b+2]=t;a[b+3]=n},keySize:8});u.AES=p._createHelper(d)})();
```

And the questions you have asked maybe

[this link can help](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers)

Hope this helps!!

Updated code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="aes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_aes()
    {
  var plaintext = "0f71bc632c6aa13da599f310a54f0d280bcea1cbd96bbd214c5c3f9be7694de96755779a957416e8d8b1ebb635ad5f4";
        var key = "0123456789abcdef";
  var parameters = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ciphertext : (plaintext)});
  var original = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(parameters,key,{iv:key, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = plaintext;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = parameters.ciphertext;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = original.toString();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>AES Test</h1>
<p><strong>Plaintext:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output1"></span></p>
<p><strong>Paramete.ciphertext:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output2"></span></p>
<p><strong>Decrypted:</strong>&nbsp;<span id="output3"></span></p>
<p></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Go! " onclick="test_aes();"/></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks Tushar --- however, this solution does not work for me, in that I need to decrypt something that I received from the server;  looks like what I need is a conversion from the ciphertext in raw bytes (or however it may be encoded -- hex, base64, etc.) to the object that CrytpJS.decrypt expects.  How can I do that?

Comment: In that case, you can use                                                                                 
 var parameters = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
                ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
                });  to create parameters and supply this to decrypt function

Comment: Thanks again @Tushar --- still not working;  I'm using the files that come with the `libjs-cryptojs` package in Ubuntu 18.04 (showing as version `3.1.2+dfsg-2`).  You only include aes.js;  if I do that, I get error `ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined`;  I'm forced to include `core.js`, `cipher-core.js`, and `enc-base64.js` --- with those, I get error `TypeError: EvpKDF is undefined`  (even if I include `evpkdf.js` as well).  I'm including them all before `aes.js`, in the order I mentioned them here. Any additional tips?

Comment: BTW, this is the up-to-date decryption code in the "minimal" test page: `var parameters = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext) });
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(parameters,key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);`

Comment: Strangely, my aes.js file (with a _character-by-character-identical header_ as yours) looks nowhere near the one you posted.  If I download and use yours, I now get error: `Error: Malformed UTF-8 data`.  Notice: my string is the output of an encryption produced by a C++ program using OpenSSL (the program outputs the hex-encoded version of the ciphertext that OpenSSL produces).  The IV I use is the same key ("0123456789abcdef"), and it is AES128 in CBC mode.  Do I need to adjust my `CipherParams.create` statement?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't found good answer but below code works and doesn't give error but shows blank sometimes, may this link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327136/how-to-decrypt-aes-ecb-using-crypto-js/20170106

Comment: Thanks Tushar --- at this point in time, I could make AES decryption work with the native API (SubtleCrypto) recommended earlier in this thread.  Being a native tool and well supported, I'm in principle happy to use it.  I'm just *really* furious and baffled about the fact that SubtleCrypto does _not_ do HMAC!!  (I mean, seriously --- how pathetic is that?!!)